# Set Color Attribute for Simple Product Programmatically

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, custom-options

I'm going to set an attribute value to simple product programmatically. I have used below code:

```
$configurableAttributes = json_decode($simpleProduct['configurable_attribute'], true);
// array('color' => 4);     
foreach ($configurableAttributes as $key => $value) {
        //Color Attribute
        $attr = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($key);
        // Black
        $attributeOption = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($value);

        $product->setData($key,$attributeOption);
        $product->save();
     }
```

I have also tried:

```
$product->setCustomAttribute($key,$attributeOption);
```

But when check in grid in Catalog. It show that the product have not attribute "Color" value. I'm wondering where I was wrong? Someone please  help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue seems to be in below code

```
$attributeOption = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($value);
$product->setData($key,$attributeOption);
```

You are assigning option label to the product instead you should assign the option value. Try below code

```
$product->setData($key,$value);
```

Comment: Yes. It must be the id instead of the label. Thanks!